# muestra ultimo registro al leer txt y mostrar datos en datagridview c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

Estoy leyendo las  lineas de un archivo txt con c#, uso una lista y la envio como datasource a un datagridview, el problema que tengo es que solo me muestra el ultimo registro de mi txt e imprime solo ese registro

```html
            DatosReporte obj = new DatosReporte();
            List<DatosReporte> lstInfo = new List<DatosReporte>();
            int counter = 0;
            string line;
             
            System.IO.StreamReader file =
                new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt");

            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(line);
                obj.SeqTransit = line;
                lstInfo.Add(obj);
                counter++;
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = lstInfo;
            file.Close();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues si.. veamos tu codigo...

```
//recorremos el archivo
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(line);
    //a este objeto (que feo nombre) le cambiamos esta propiedad
    obj.SeqTransit = line;
    //agregamos este objeto a la lista... 
    lstInfo.Add(obj);
    counter++;
}
```

o sea.. agregamos, siempre, el mismo objeto a la lista.. y el objeto tiene como propiedad SeqTransit siempre la misma!!!

se entiende? lo que tenes que hacer, es un nuevo objeto en cada vuelta y eso agregarlo a la lista..

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(line);
    obj = new obj();
    obj.SeqTransit = line;
    lstInfo.Add(obj);
    counter++;
}
```